# Highlight text on a PDF

Tags: android, pdf, android-ndk, mupdf

I have compiled [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/) correctly and have been able to run the sample app without an issue, but:

**Problem**

I want to have a functionality like `highlights,underlines, sticky notes, arrows, lines, ovals, rectangles, freehand drawings and text boxes on which user long pressed by his finger`, as in [RepliGo PDF Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cerience.reader.app&feature=search_result) pdf reader and others.

I searched a lot, but didn't find any relevant way, link or hint to achieve the desired feature.

Can someone share any idea on how to achieve the aforementioned functionality?
It would be even more helpful if someone can explain it by sharing some code or example.

Comment: MuPDF is just an engine to render PDF content. I'm afraid you have to code the rest. You have to handle the user actions you wish, with the behaviour you want. And come back, if you get stuck with an exact problem...

Comment: @Chirag Patel did you find any solution for this?

Comment: MuPDF displays pdf as images. I'm quite sure you can do all your functionalities if your display your pdf files as text.

Comment: MuPDF is a viewer, what you want is a bit more complex, e.g. Xournal.

Comment: you should use itext library to show pdf and it also has all the features to implement through code  you want

Comment: try itext, as it shows data in text form

Answer (score 1):

As MuPdf doesn't expose apis for the features you require, I suggest using the PDFTron sdk library for android.

As you can see on their docs page, it supports lot of annotation related pdf features:

> Ready-to-Use Tools for Rapid Development - including support for
>   advanced features such as text selection, full text search; links;
>   bookmark navigation and manipulation; interactive forms; various
>   annotation capabilities to enable PDF markup (text highlight,
>   underline, strikeout, squiggly, line, rectangle, ellipse, arrow,
>   sticky note, and free-hand tool mode, etc.).

http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/android_pdf_library.html